# Split string into all possible search strings

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I am looking to store all possible search matches in a database so I can get away from doing a `LIKE %term%` query. Is there a way to split up the following string?

```
STRING = LG_THELASTWITCHHUNTER_PREORDERTRAILER_HD_2CH_EN_PTBRSUB_16X9_240_2398_DIGITAL_FINAL.mov
```

Part one would be on every word separator we split the sub-word. So we have:

```
SUBWORDS = 'LG', 'THELASTWITCHHUNTER', ...
```

Part two would be getting all possible consecutive letter combinations for that word. For example:

```
LG ==> 'L', 'G', 'LG
THELASTWITCHHUNTER ==> 'T', 'TH', 'THE', 'H', 'HE', 'HEL', etc.
```

Is there a way to do this, or perhaps a better approach that what I'm using above. To provide context, using a LIKE search takes about 15s to do with all the paths I have --

[image]

The end goal is to extract all the word strings. That is:

```
LG, THE, LAST, WITCH, HUNTER, PREORDER, TRAILER, HD, 2CH, EN, PTBR, SUB, 16X8, 2398, DIGITAL, FINAL, MOV
```

Comment: I hope you don't mean all possible substrings of a given string, because that gets very big very quickly.

Comment: How do you know that the word is `TRAILER` and not `TRAIL`?

Comment: @AdamSmith -- you don't, that's why I want to be as aggressive as possible with the stemming, so we could grab both of those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to breaking up the string, you can just use

```
STRING.split('_')
```

For getting all the substrings:

```
title = 'cats'
substrings = {title[a:a+k] for k in range(1,1+len(title)) 
             for a in range(1+len(title)-k)}
```

This gives:

['c', 'a', 't', 's', 'ca', 'at', 'ts', 'cat', 'ats', 'cats']

For a strings of length n, you'll get (n+1)n/2 nonempty substrings.

EDIT: Changed to set comprehension instead of list comprehension to eliminate duplicates.  For loner titles, we can expect duplicate one- and two-letter strings, at least, and we want to cull the unique substrings.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1: splitting words

```
wordlist = string.split('_')
```

this is assuming you want every word that is separated by an `_`

Part 2: extracting all word strings

this can be a lot of different words so I would be careful with memory but...

```
splitlist = []
for word in wordlist:
  for i in range(len(word)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(word)+1):
      splitlist.append(word[i:j])
```

I suggest putting a check to make sure the new addition is not already in splitlist but yeah thats basically what you need right"?

Comment: You can just make `splitlist` a set and use `splitlist.add` instead of `splitlist.append` to eliminate duplicates.